# How to set x value in between parameters

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Basically I want the TotalScore to be between 50 and 80 but with my current code it sends out the email if its greater than 50 (yes) or less than 80(no because that would happen everytime)

If you see the code down below, thats about all I figured out

```
if(TotalScore > 50, TotalScore < 80){
// Fetch the email address
var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TEST").getRange("F2");
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();

// Send Alert Email.
var message = 'Your score is alright, but you can improve!Your score is: ' + TotalScore; // Second column
var subject = 'Improvement Score Alert';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

Comment: in javascript it evaluates expressions from left to right ( comma separated ), and concludes for, which is last in the order, in your case it is { TotalScore < 80} . Thus everytime it is executing. Use logical '&&' operator to connect both the conditions

Answer (score 0):

[**Multiple conditions**](https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-specify-multiple-conditions-in-an-if-statement-in-Javascript) in if should be seperated by `&&` or `||`. In your code the `,` should be replaced by `&&`

```
if(TotalScore > 50 && TotalScore < 80){
    //           ^^^^^
    // Fetch the email address
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TEST").getRange("F2");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();

    // Send Alert Email.
    var message = 'Your score is alright, but you can improve!Your score is: ' + TotalScore; // Second column
    var subject = 'Improvement Score Alert';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```